# How to use checkpointing in spark with Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

How does checkpointing in spark with Kubernetes work?

Comment: By default, why do you think it would work any different from local filesystem that it needs specific documentation? Spark standalone mode would have the same limitation. You need to setup MinIO/Hadoop Ozone/GlusterFS/Ceph as a shared filesystem for distributed checkpoints

Comment: yes have difference on k8. and we haven't those (MinIO/Hadoop Ozone/GlusterFS/Ceph ) file systems.

Comment: If anyone have example checkpoint with K8 in spark it would be  appreciated.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Why do you think it should work any differently than the defaults? Checkpoints are written to /tmp of the executor filesystems, which are just distributed, ephemeral containers rather than specific machines

Comment: kubernate not support any distributed file system and while im using checkpointing it throw exception to me like org.apache.spark.SparkException: Checkpoint RDD has a different number of partitions from original RDD. Original RDD [ID: 36484, num of partitions: 200]; Checkpoint RDD [ID: 36485, num of partitions: 0].

Comment: It supports all the filesystem options I mentioned. You just need to install them separately.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.